# When a django form is submitted, does the POST request contain model ID's?

Tags: django

I have the following django form:

```
class AssayCompoundForm(forms.ModelForm):
titrated_compound = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Compound.objects.all())
fixed_compound = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Compound.objects.all())
fixed_concentration = forms.FloatField()

class Meta:
    model = AssayCompound
    fields = ['titrated_compound', 'fixed_compound', 'fixed_concentration']
```

and the following HTML:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="assay-compound-form">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
        <label class="form-input">Titrated Compound</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
        {{ new_assay_compound_form.titrated_compound }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
        <label class="form-input">Fixed Compound</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
        {{ new_assay_compound_form.fixed_compound }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
        <label class="form-input">Fixed Concentration</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
        {{ new_assay_compound_form.fixed_concentration }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
</div>
<input id="assay-compound-form-submit" type="submit" name="add-assay-compound" style="display:none">
```

The request.POST that is generated by this form looks like this:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['blah'], 'titrated_compound': ['3'], 'fixed_compound': ['5'], 'fixed_concentration': ['4'], 'add-assay-compound': ['Submit']}>
```

My question is this: are the lists of strings for the user-selected 'titrated_compound' and 'fixed_compound' the model ID's assigned by Django?  Or are they the indices of the indices of the ordered list generated by 'Compound.objects.all()'?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specify the `to_field_name` attribute these are the primary keys of each model (by the default the `id` field autogenerated by Django). Check [this ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name) and you can also take a look at [the code here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/_modules/django/forms/models/#ModelChoiceField). The `prepare_value` and `to_python` methods are of particular interest.